# Which moves can’t be used in raid battles?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

While doing max raid battles, I will occasionally get a message that says, or something similar to:

> “[X] move has failed; [Boss] protected itself”

This message has appeared for both my Pokémon and the boss itself.

So far, these are the ones I know do not work

- Explosion (used by boss, failed)
- Grass Knot (probably due to damage calculation)
- Destiny Bond (don’t judge me)

What are all the moves that can’t be used in raid battles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OHKO moves (such as [Horn Drill](https://www.serebii.net/attackdex-swsh/horndrill.shtml)) won't have any affect on a Dynamax Pokemon,
***except*** when they have a shield.
The move removes 2 shield points (rather than the usual 1),
but it does no damage if they do not have a shield.

The [Weight Moves](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Moves_affected_by_weight) (such as [Heavy Slam](https://www.serebii.net/attackdex-swsh/heavyslam.shtml) and the Grass Knot you mentioned) will also not have any affect, your Pokemon will not use those moves against Dynamax Pokemon as Dynamax have a weight of ??? as shown in the Pokedex.

It seems that moves that affect the held item, such as Knock Off and Bug Bite don't work as well.

Also moves that affect the Pokemon's ability, such as Skill Swap will not work.

Lastly moves that send the pokemon away, such as Whirlwind do not work.

[Paul's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/361083/25368) is certainly great with [that list](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/maxraidbattles.shtml), however Serebii actually has a [second list](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/dynamax.shtml) on a different page that includes the weight moves and others.

As mentioned in [Pyrite's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361082/which-moves-can-t-be-used-in-raid-battles/361104#comment510640_361104), Curse ([when used by a Ghost type](https://www.serebii.net/attackdex-swsh/curse.shtml)) does actually work.
[Here is proof I recorded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkaZQ5Wlen0&feature=youtu.be).

So in total it seems the list of moves are as follows:

- Bug Bite
- Circle Throw
- Destiny Bond
- Disable
- Encore
- Entrainment
- Explosion
- Fissure
- Grass Knot
- Guillotine
- Heat Crash
- Heavy Slam
- Horn Drill
- Incinerate
- Instruct
- Knock Off
- Low Kick
- Perish Song
- Pluck
- Roar
- Self-Destruct
- Sheer Cold
- Skill Swap
- Super Fang
- Whirlwind

Comment: Perish Song works, if Gigantamax Gengar uses it on your team tho.
So there are some move that will work if the Wild Pokemon uses them.

Comment: I don't see Curse listed on serebii's page. Are you sure it fails? I've heard otherwise, where it still works and does % damage every turn, but the damage is just a lot less than normal because the damage is calculated without using the raid's massive HP increase. Same goes for moves like Toxic and Leech Seed.

Comment: Moves that inflict status effects or stat drops do not work on the Dynamax Pokemon if it has its' barrier up.  This is most apparent with Dynamax moves not inflicting their intended effects (stat drops).

Comment: @Pyritie Curse is listed, its the second move listed under the "Battling" header here: https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/maxraidbattles.shtml However I can go into a battle today after work and confirm.

Comment: @Pyritie you are correct however that it does actually work! Just tested it, editing answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [max raid battle page on Serebii.net](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/maxraidbattles.shtml), the forbidden moves are:

- Bug Bite
- Curse
- Destiny Bond
- Explosion
- Incinerate
- Knock Off
- Perish Song
- Pluck
- Self-Destruct
- Super Fang

Most likely, self-killing moves are disabled to keep a particularly dense player from losing the battle by sacrificing their pokemon repeatedly. High percentage based damage moves are also disabled, as well as anything involving berries for some reason.

Comment: You should also add that any explicit status effect moves like will-o-wisp and thunder wave will also give that message if the raid boss has a barrier up.

Comment: So berry related moves are out but Trick and other held item shenanigans are still in?

Comment: Going to have to try these when I get a chance, I can't play the game right now.

Comment: I've definitely seen Curse used in a raid. Maybe that one only applies to Ghosts?

Comment: That's certainly possible, since it doesn't do % damage when the pokemon is not ghost type. I'll have to try that too.

Comment: @Studoku Trick doesn’t seem to be an option in raid battles, but it’s very big shenanigan in double battles (Trick w/Eject Button is one that I saw recently)

Answer (score 1):

I came here to find out about final gambit.

Final gambit fails when used in raid.

I just tried it against shuckle*